# Adding a lot of data to core data while keeping the UI responsive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ios, core-data

I'm looking for a way to add a whole load of data to core data while keeping the little activity indicator spinning on the UI. I tried adding the data on another thread but since learned that core data is not thread safe, and I get all kinds of errors. Can anyone suggest another approach to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the data is loading on background thread, what do you try to do to received the error? Do you click on anything that would read or write to CoreData?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is not thread-safe, but that just means you have to code appropriately, rather avoiding them entirely. To keep your UI responsive/up-to-date, you'll need to use threads.

Apple's documentation on the subject is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html), and [this blog post](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/) is an excellent walk-through of using multiple threads with Core Data, and some of the pitfalls involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate managed object context for each thread. There's some additional work you need to do to make changes from other contexts available to your main thread's context: see [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) for a full discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Most useful example is a core data XML downloading from iOS sample code. If u don't have access, please let me know and I will write here is a main structure of it.
There is a complex custom delegate techniques  from u UIviewController to nsoperation delegate, this is important for u to start showing content immediately to user and show a progress of sync.
In AppStore u can see my "snow IXC" app, where u can see this techniques implemented for indicate user in their UIviewController about progress. It's free for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I avoid background threads with a loading indicator (I use DSActivityView but this should work with other implementations):

In your code when you are going to be displaying the indicator run all the code to show the indicator first.  After that code have a separate method call to do all the loading work.  Call it by using the method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadMethodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Normally the app will go straight into the loading code without waiting to show the indicator view.  By calling it this way it will first finish displaying the indicator before it moves into the loading code.